# Duplicate data in kibana from logstash

Tags: ruby, logstash, kibana

I'm trying display some Mongo data that I've been collecting using logstash using the Mongostat tool. It displays things with a suffix like "b", "k", "g" to signify byte, kilobyte, gigabyte, which is fine if I'm just reading the output, but I want to throw this into kibana and display it in a graphical format to see trends.

I've done this with several other log files and everything is fine. When I use a grok filter everything is fine but I've added a Ruby filter and now data seems to be duplicated in all fields other than the logstash generated fields and my new field created in my Ruby filter.

Here is the relevant parts of my conf file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/mongodb/mongostat.log"
    type => "mongostat"
    start_position => "end"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "mongostat" {
     grok {
       patterns_dir => "/opt/logstash/patterns"
       match => ["message","###a bunch of filtering that i know works###"]
       add_tag => "mongostat"
     }
    
        if [mongoMappedQualifier] == 'b' {
            ruby {
               code => "event['mongoMappedKB'] = event['mongoMapped'].to_f / 1024"
            }
        }
        if [mongoMappedQualifier] == 'k' {
            ruby {
               code => "event['mongoMappedKB'] = event['mongoMapped'].to_f * 1"
            }
        }
        if [mongoMappedQualifier] == 'm' {
            ruby {
               code => "event['mongoMappedKB'] = event['mongoMapped'].to_f * 1024"
            }
        }
        if [mongoMappedQualifier] == 'g' {
            ruby {
               code => "event['mongoMappedKB'] = event['mongoMapped'].to_f * 1048576"
            }
        }
  }
}

output {
   if [type] == "mongostat" {
    redis {
       host => "redis"
       data_type => "list"
       key => "logstash-mongostat"
     }
   }
}
```

Any idea why or how this can be fixed?

[image: Kibana graph with duplicated data]

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. AFAICT your Kibana screendump doesn't show any duplication.

Comment: @MagnusBäck in the screenshot look under the mongoTime and mongoMapped, under there you will see a comma that separates values which is what i'm talking about when i say there's duplication. there shouldn't be any values with commas in them. similar to this issue: https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-2085 but my setup isn't the same so the fix doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: also, as i said before this only happened after i put in the ruby filter. before there were no duplicate values which i find very strange

Comment: Solved: I found a stray config file on one of the servers, the name was changed and Saltstack which is the automated deploy tool we use did not catch it and remove it (I should have caught that, I removed it on one server but not the other which is why there was duplication but not for every row)